# How to parse HTML files with Pentaho?

Tags: web-scraping, jsoup, pentaho

I have a html file and I wanna parse the HTML with some advanced css selectors.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

Pentaho doesn't offer you a native way to do that, most of the answers in the internet will lead you to use regular expression, which is okay but sometimes you need something more advanced than that.

In that scenario you can use [`Modified Java Script Value`](https://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Modified+Java+Script+Value) step. **You can use java code mixed with javascript.**

In the following example I used [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) library, just download the `jsoup-x.x.x.jar` and put in the `data-integration\lib` folder of Pentaho. **Restart it.**

Next you'll add a `Modified Java Script Value` with the following example code:

```
doc = org.jsoup.Jsoup.parse(myHTMLString);
myTextOfNodeWithAdvancedSelect = doc.select("body > table:nth-child(3) ").text();
```

where `myHTMLString` is the string you wanna parse (it can be obtained through `HTTP Client`step or some other way.)

Don't forget to add the variable in the table of `Fields` **with the same name** and set the type of variable in the way illustrated below

[image]